# AngularJS suitable to build components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks

I'm currently working on a PHP web application which consists of about ~200 different views. Most of them just display tables or forms.

However, on about 10 pages (not related in any way) users could benefit from dynamic/async components to avoid constant page reloads.

I read a lot about AngularJS being used for single-page applications. The data binding and a lot of the other features could definitly be used for our components. But our applications isn't single-page at all, is AngularJS nonetheless suitable? Or is there any other framework which might be suitable to build some self-contained components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a JavaScript framework suitable for every type of application, not just single-page apps. Its routing functionality is just one of the major advantages. You can use AngularJS in multi-page applications to populate tables for example. Using AngularJS to make a dynamic pagination is also possible.

My point is, although AngularJS can be used to make single-page apps, it can also be used in traditional pages to simplify a lot of things.